# Can you put goto and if then into one line?

Tags: performance, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to put the goto and the if then command in the same line because so I don't have to make a another BAT files to get the job done.
Here an example of the code that I am makeing so far:

```
@echo off
SET _cliportaskkill=0
SET _startffox=0

If "%_cliportaskkill%"=="2" goto everything
If "%_cliportaskkill%"=="1" goto cliponly
If "%_cliportaskkill%"=="0" goto taskkillonly


:cliponly
echo|set /p=username@email.com|clip
EXIT

:taskkillonly
TASKKILL /F /T /IM Greenshot.exe & TASKKILL /F /T /IM iprntctl.exe & TASKKILL /F /T /IM iprntlgn.exe & TASKKILL /F /T /IM smax4pnp.exe & TASKKILL /F /T /IM ZenNotifyIcon.exe & TASKKILL /F /T /IM ZenUserDaemon.exe & TASKKILL /F /T /IM RAVBg64.exe & TASKKILL /F /T /IM nwtray.exe & TASKKILL /F /T /IM RtkNGUI64.exe & TASKKILL /F /T /IM BingSvc.exe & TASKKILL /F /T /IM Spotify.exe & TASKKILL /F /T /IM SpotifyWebHelper.exe & TASKKILL /F /T /IM FacebookGameroom.exe & TASKKILL /F /T /IM "Facebook Gameroom Browser.exe" & TASKKILL /F /T /IM zapp.exe & TASKKILL /F /T /IM steamwebhelper.exe & TASKKILL /F /T /IM Steam.exe & TASKKILL /F /T /IM lync.exe
EXIT

:everything
echo|set /p=username@email.com|clip

TASKKILL /F /T /IM Greenshot.exe & TASKKILL /F /T /IM iprntctl.exe & TASKKILL /F /T /IM iprntlgn.exe & TASKKILL /F /T /IM smax4pnp.exe & TASKKILL /F /T /IM ZenNotifyIcon.exe & TASKKILL /F /T /IM ZenUserDaemon.exe & TASKKILL /F /T /IM RAVBg64.exe & TASKKILL /F /T /IM nwtray.exe & TASKKILL /F /T /IM RtkNGUI64.exe & TASKKILL /F /T /IM BingSvc.exe & TASKKILL /F /T /IM Spotify.exe & TASKKILL /F /T /IM SpotifyWebHelper.exe & TASKKILL /F /T /IM FacebookGameroom.exe & TASKKILL /F /T /IM "Facebook Gameroom Browser.exe" & TASKKILL /F /T /IM zapp.exe & TASKKILL /F /T /IM steamwebhelper.exe & TASKKILL /F /T /IM Steam.exe & TASKKILL /F /T /IM lync.exe
EXIT

===================================================================================================================

@echo off
If "%_startffox%"=="1" goto newwindow
If "%_startffox%"=="0" goto newtab

:newwindow
CD /D "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox"
firefox.exe "https://www.outlook.com/" "http://everybodyedits.com/" "http://www.kongregate.com/accounts/username/recently-played"
EXIT

:newtab
CD /D "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox"
firefox.exe -new-tab "https://www.outlook.com/" -new-tab "http://everybodyedits.com/" -new-tab "http://www.kongregate.com/accounts/username/recently-played"
EXIT
```

Whcih is used for this BAT file:
Old verson

```
@echo on
START "taskkilling and cliping" CMD /c "@echo off & echo|set /p=username@email.com|clip & TASKKILL /F /T /IM Greenshot.exe & TASKKILL /F /T /IM iprntctl.exe & TASKKILL /F /T /IM iprntlgn.exe & TASKKILL /F /T /IM smax4pnp.exe & TASKKILL /F /T /IM ZenNotifyIcon.exe & TASKKILL /F /T /IM ZenUserDaemon.exe & TASKKILL /F /T /IM RAVBg64.exe & TASKKILL /F /T /IM nwtray.exe & TASKKILL /F /T /IM RtkNGUI64.exe & TASKKILL /F /T /IM BingSvc.exe & TASKKILL /F /T /IM Spotify.exe & TASKKILL /F /T /IM SpotifyWebHelper.exe & TASKKILL /F /T /IM FacebookGameroom.exe & TASKKILL /F /T /IM "Facebook Gameroom Browser.exe" & TASKKILL /F /T /IM zapp.exe & TASKKILL /F /T /IM steamwebhelper.exe & TASKKILL /F /T /IM Steam.exe & TASKKILL /F /T /IM lync.exe"

START "start new firefox in three new tabs" CMD /c "@echo off & CD /D "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox" & firefox.exe "https://www.outlook.com/" "http://everybodyedits.com/" "http://www.kongregate.com/accounts/username/recently-played""
```

So I am trying make a BAT file that have options that I can use for my new verson that I use when I log on to the computer.
So far I try testing the one of code through a different BAT file so here what I have so far:

```
SET _startffox=0
CHOICE /C wt /m "w open new window, t open new tab"
IF errorlevel 2 set _startffox=0 & goto line
IF errorlevel 1 set _startffox=1 & goto line

:line
pause & echo %_startffox%
(echo on & (If "%_startffox%"=="1" goto newwindow); (If "%_startffox%"=="0" goto newtab); (:newwindow & ECHO "go to new window firefox" & ECHO "Hi windows" & pause & EXIT); (:newtab & ECHO "go to new tabs firefox" & ECHO "Hi tabs" & pause & EXIT))
pause
```

so far it does not work the way I wahntd to work.

Comment: Why do you need a `goto` at all there?

Comment: No you cannot put all of that parenthesized code on one line.

Comment: You certainly don't use a semicolon as a command separator. And for those huge taskkill lines, why not use a `For` loop, i.e. `For %%A In (Greenshot.exe,iprntctl.exe,iprntlgn.exe,smax4pnp.exe,ZenNotifyIcon.exe,ZenUserDaemon.exe,RAVBg64.exe,nwtray.exe,RtkNGUI64.exe,BingSvc.exe,Spotify.exe,SpotifyWebHelper.exe,FacebookGameroom.exe,"Facebook Gameroom Browser.exe",zapp.exe,steamwebhelper.exe,Steam.exe,lync.exe) Do TaskKill /F /IM %%A /T`,instead.

Comment: why on earth do you want to create such long lines? It's a script - keep one command per line. When needed, use (code blocks). It's easy, it's readable and doesn't do unintended/unexpected things.

Comment: Like @stephan says. Lentghy lines are unwanted. Also you set a variable to 0 then use if 1 and 2 which it cannot be aince you set it to 0. You need to simplify this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal

SET "_cliportaskkill=0"
SET "_startffox=0"

If "%_cliportaskkill%"=="2" call :everything
If "%_cliportaskkill%"=="1" call :cliponly
If "%_cliportaskkill%"=="0" call :taskkillonly

If "%_startffox%"=="1" call :newwindow
If "%_startffox%"=="0" call :newtab
EXIT /B


:cliponly
echo|set /p=username@email.com|clip
EXIT /B


:taskkillonly
TASKKILL /F /T^
 /IM Greenshot.exe^
 /IM iprntctl.exe^
 /IM iprntlgn.exe^
 /IM smax4pnp.exe^
 /IM ZenNotifyIcon.exe^
 /IM ZenUserDaemon.exe^
 /IM RAVBg64.exe^
 /IM nwtray.exe^
 /IM RtkNGUI64.exe^
 /IM BingSvc.exe^
 /IM Spotify.exe^
 /IM SpotifyWebHelper.exe^
 /IM FacebookGameroom.exe^
 /IM "Facebook Gameroom Browser.exe"^
 /IM zapp.exe^
 /IM steamwebhelper.exe^
 /IM Steam.exe^
 /IM lync.exe
EXIT /B


:everything
echo|set /p=username@email.com|clip

TASKKILL /F /T^
 /IM Greenshot.exe^
 /IM iprntctl.exe^
 /IM iprntlgn.exe^
 /IM smax4pnp.exe^
 /IM ZenNotifyIcon.exe^
 /IM ZenUserDaemon.exe^
 /IM RAVBg64.exe^
 /IM nwtray.exe^
 /IM RtkNGUI64.exe^
 /IM BingSvc.exe^
 /IM Spotify.exe^
 /IM SpotifyWebHelper.exe^
 /IM FacebookGameroom.exe^
 /IM "Facebook Gameroom Browser.exe"^
 /IM zapp.exe^
 /IM steamwebhelper.exe^
 /IM Steam.exe^
 /IM lync.exe
EXIT /B


:newwindow
CD /D "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox"
firefox.exe^
 "https://www.outlook.com/"^
 "http://everybodyedits.com/"^
 "http://www.kongregate.com/accounts/username/recently-played"
EXIT /B


:newtab
CD /D "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox"
firefox.exe^
 -new-tab "https://www.outlook.com/"^
 -new-tab "http://everybodyedits.com/"^
 -new-tab "http://www.kongregate.com/accounts/username/recently-played"
EXIT /B
```

> Can you put goto and if then into one line?

Yes.

Labels though need to be at the start of a line and can be preceded
by spaces used for indenting.

Advise you use `call` instead of `goto` in many instances as it will
give good program flow as `call` goes to the label and then returns
back to the line of the caller. Using `goto` goes to the label and
then you may need to use `goto` again to go somewhere else and thus
you go all over and may eventually may become lost. So using `call`
allows all the main code to be grouped together and call labels as
needed.

`taskkill` can handle multiple images in the one process thus may be
 more efficient.

Use `^` to continue the command over to the next line to line up the
arguments vertically. Can improve readability and maintenance.

Use of `EXIT /B` can exit a label or the script.
Use of `EXIT` closes the interpreter which is usually undesirable
for a script.

Be free to update the code using `CHOICE` or any other new ideas
you may have.

---

Example of indented label.

```
@echo off
if not "%~1" == "" call :level0 %*
exit /b

:level0
echo test indented label
    :level1
    echo "%~1"
    shift
    if not "%~1" == "" goto :level1
echo done
exit /b
```

Call the example script with arguments i.e. `main.cmd 1 2 3`. The interpreter will find `:level1` even though it is indented.

Comment: Thank you for providing the solution.

Comment: Forgot to add the `CHOICE` before the IF cliportaskkill list

Comment: And how do you indent the labels? Can you show me a example of an indentd line for the label before the commands?

Answer (score 0):

Still haven't figure out how to put in one line and updated [michael_heath](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49932950/8876148) code with a litte bit of mine:

```
@echo on
setlocal

CHOICE /C ectfx /m "e do everything, c clip only, t taskkill only, f skip this, x close this"
If errorlevel 5 EXIT /B
If errorlevel 4 goto :choiceff
If errorlevel 3 call :taskkillonly
If errorlevel 2 call :cliponly
If errorlevel 1 call :everything

:choiceff
CHOICE /C wtx /m "w open new window, t open new tab, x close this"
If errorlevel 3 EXIT /B
If errorlevel 2 call :newtab
If errorlevel 1 call :newwindow
EXIT /B


:cliponly
echo|set /p=username@email.com|clip
EXIT /B


:taskkillonly
TASKKILL /F /T^
 /IM Greenshot.exe^
 /IM iprntctl.exe^
 /IM iprntlgn.exe^
 /IM smax4pnp.exe^
 /IM ZenNotifyIcon.exe^
 /IM ZenUserDaemon.exe^
 /IM RAVBg64.exe^
 /IM nwtray.exe^
 /IM RtkNGUI64.exe^
 /IM BingSvc.exe^
 /IM Spotify.exe^
 /IM SpotifyWebHelper.exe^
 /IM FacebookGameroom.exe^
 /IM "Facebook Gameroom Browser.exe"^
 /IM zapp.exe^
 /IM steamwebhelper.exe^
 /IM Steam.exe^
 /IM lync.exe
EXIT /B


:everything
echo|set /p=username@email.com|clip

TASKKILL /F /T^
 /IM Greenshot.exe^
 /IM iprntctl.exe^
 /IM iprntlgn.exe^
 /IM smax4pnp.exe^
 /IM ZenNotifyIcon.exe^
 /IM ZenUserDaemon.exe^
 /IM RAVBg64.exe^
 /IM nwtray.exe^
 /IM RtkNGUI64.exe^
 /IM BingSvc.exe^
 /IM Spotify.exe^
 /IM SpotifyWebHelper.exe^
 /IM FacebookGameroom.exe^
 /IM "Facebook Gameroom Browser.exe"^
 /IM zapp.exe^
 /IM steamwebhelper.exe^
 /IM Steam.exe^
 /IM lync.exe
EXIT /B


:newwindow
CD /D "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox"
firefox.exe^
 "https://www.outlook.com/"^
 "http://everybodyedits.com/"^
 "http://www.kongregate.com/accounts/username/recently-played"
EXIT /B


:newtab
CD /D "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox"
firefox.exe^
 -new-tab "https://www.outlook.com/"^
 -new-tab "http://everybodyedits.com/"^
 -new-tab "http://www.kongregate.com/accounts/username/recently-played"
EXIT /B
```

Remove the VAR `cliportaskkill` and `startffox` from the code and a litte bug where pressing t to taskkill only after it finish the code it go to the next errorlevel and call the `:cliponly` code before it move on to the next choice command (this where I put an `& goto :label` to stop this bug but may break this BAT file when put into one line.)

**P.S.** In the near future I am thinking I could put the `cliportaskkill` and `startffox` VAR back in so that I can use it for parallel codes or two instances without waiting for the other codes to finish (without doing in another BAT files as well.)

---

I'ev set echo to on and here the output of the codes.

```
>setlocal

>CHOICE /C ectfx /m "e do everything, c clip only, t taskkill only, f skip this, x close this"
e do everything, c clip only, t taskkill only, f skip this, x close this [E,C,T,F,X]?T

>If errorlevel 5 EXIT /B

>If errorlevel 4 goto :choiceff

>If errorlevel 3 call :taskkillonly

>TASKKILL /F /T /IM Greenshot.exe /IM iprntctl.exe /IM iprntlgn.exe /IM smax4pnp.exe /IM ZenNotifyIcon.ex
e /IM ZenUserDaemon.exe /IM RAVBg64.exe /IM nwtray.exe /IM RtkNGUI64.exe /IM BingSvc.exe /IM Spotify.exe /IM SpotifyWebHelper.exe /IM F
acebookGameroom.exe /IM "Facebook Gameroom Browser.exe" /IM zapp.exe /IM steamwebhelper.exe /IM Steam.exe /IM lync.exe
ERROR: The process "Greenshot.exe" not found.
ERROR: The process "iprntctl.exe" not found.
ERROR: The process "iprntlgn.exe" not found.
ERROR: The process "smax4pnp.exe" not found.
ERROR: The process "ZenNotifyIcon.exe" not found.
ERROR: The process "ZenUserDaemon.exe" not found.
ERROR: The process "RAVBg64.exe" not found.
ERROR: The process "nwtray.exe" not found.
ERROR: The process "RtkNGUI64.exe" not found.
ERROR: The process "BingSvc.exe" not found.
ERROR: The process "Spotify.exe" not found.
ERROR: The process "SpotifyWebHelper.exe" not found.
ERROR: The process "FacebookGameroom.exe" not found.
ERROR: The process "Facebook Gameroom Browser.exe" not found.
ERROR: The process "zapp.exe" not found.
ERROR: The process "steamwebhelper.exe" not found.
ERROR: The process "Steam.exe" not found.
ERROR: The process "lync.exe" not found.

>EXIT /B

>If errorlevel 2 call :cliponly

>echo | set /p=username@email.com  | clip

>EXIT /B

>If errorlevel 1 call :everything

>CHOICE /C wtx /m "w open new window, t open new tab, x close this"
w open new window, t open new tab, x close this [W,T,X]?
```

As you can see after the taskkill block it go to the next block which is the clip code before going to the next `CHOICE` commmand (for some reason it does not go to the next block of codes.)

I've press T for this one

```
>If errorlevel 3 EXIT /B

>If errorlevel 2 call :newtab

>CD /D "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox"

>firefox.exe -new-tab "https://www.outlook.com/" -new-tab "http://everybodyedits.com/" -new-tab "
http://www.kongregate.com/accounts/username/recently-played"

>ECHO newtab!
newtab!

>pause
Press any key to continue . . .

>EXIT /B

>If errorlevel 1 call :newwindow

>CD /D "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox"

>firefox.exe "https://www.outlook.com/" "http://everybodyedits.com/" "http://www.kongregate.com/a
ccounts/username/recently-played"

>ECHO newwindow!
newwindow!

>pause
Press any key to continue . . .
```

I've add an `echo` and `pause` to test if it do the same for this `CHOICE` command and it start the next block of code after it finished the the previous code. I've tested this in a test file where I used some CHOICE, If errorlevel, calling and goto commands and same bugs happened in the test file.

Comment: are you aware that you can replace the whole `:everything` code with just `call :cliponly` and `call :taskkillonly`?

Comment: Like Stephan suggests, replace `If errorlevel 1 call :everything` with `If errorlevel 1 call :cliponly & call :taskkillonly`. That can get rid of duplicate code of the label `:everything`. You can also use arguments on called labels to run optional code etc. in the containing code.

Comment: Perhaps the bug you are referring to is that you should insert a line with `EXIT /B` before the `:choiceff` label else execution will continue into that labels code which I doubt that is what you want. Ideally, sort your changes and ask a new question if you have some new problems.